# Session counter with HttpSessionListener and session count variable access

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, counter, volatile

I saw an example with session counter in Sun's "Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages vol 2".
Counter is simply build on `HttpSessionListener` and increments/decrements session count with `sessionCreated`/`sessionDestroyed`:

```
public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {
   private int currentSessionCount = 0;

   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
       currentSessionCount++;
   }
   ...
   public int getTotalSessionCount() {
       return(totalSessionCount);
   }
   ... // counter decrement, self registering in context attribute etc.
```

Listener register itself in context, so `servlets` can access it and get counter value.
There is no synchronized block.
**Is it safe, that `currentSessionCount` is not `volatile`?**

Can `currentSessionCount` be cached in CPU register and not visible with exact value for other threads that serve request with `servlets`?

Comment: It is absolutely not safe.

Comment: You can post an answer and possibly add some solution (does simple volatile fix it?)

Comment: Actually, I may be wrong. I don't know if the servlet container manages session expiration in a queue. If it does, possibly, a single thread will only ever run through the queue and execute the `HttpSessionListener` methods.

Comment: I think that we can be 100% sure that other thread can access this object, because we can just get it as context attribute in servlet and call any method. So even if created/destroyed maybe is accesed from single thread (no race condition), we can still have a CPU-cached counter in register, for single thread (if I am not wrong - the question is about that)

Comment: In that case, yes, you are correct. I don't think the Listener is meant to be managed by anything other than the container. You'll need some `servlet` hotshots to get a final answer.

Comment: it may also depends on app server implementation. As Sotirios Delimanolis said it could be executed from some queue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification of Servlet 3.0 says (§ 11.5):

> Listener Instances and Threading
>
> [...]
>
> The container is not required to synchronize the resulting notifications
> to attribute listener classes. Listener classes that maintain state are responsible for
> the integrity of the data and should handle this case explicitly.

So no, the code is not safe. Using an AtomicCounter or synchronizing the access to the counter fixes it.

Making it volatile doean't make it safer, because ++ is not an atomic operation. So every other thread will see the new value thanks to volatile, but you might still miss increments due to a race condition reading, then incrementing the counter in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

This would be safe.

```
public class HttpSessionListenerTest implements HttpSessionListener {
    final private AtomicInteger sessionCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        sessionCount.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        sessionCount.decrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getTotalSessionCount() {
        return sessionCount.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Word of warning: i have something like that in my code base. works as long as i run it locally. deployed in production i see total session count -121. It turns out this is due to Tomcat's persisting the sessions. So you could have 121 sessions open, then you restart the server, you get a new session counter instance with the counter of course reset to 0, and then, as the 121 restored sessions close in due course, you get a negative active session count.