# Using HttpSessionListener to track the total number of session in web application

Tags: java, servlets, struts

My web application is build using servlets and struts. I wish to track the total number of session login to the application.

If the number of login exceeds a certain limit, I will refuse the login. How do I pass the total number of sessions from HttpSession to my struts Action class or Servlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class HttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static final AtomicInteger sessionCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

   @Override
   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
       sessionCount.incrementAndGet();
   }

   @Override
   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
       sessionCount.decrementAndGet();
   }

   public static int getTotalSessionCount() {
       return sessionCount.get();
   }

}
```

A primitive Integer is not thread safe. With the solution above you can acess the count of open sessions with HttpSessionListener.getTotalSessionCount() . The model of the code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17673269/1632341).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the HttpSessionListener and have a static field like the following :

```
public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  public static int totalActiveSessions;


  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    totalActiveSessions++;
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    totalActiveSessions--;
  }


}
```

and access it from anywhere like the following :

```
SessionCounterListener .totalActiveSessions
```

please give me some feedback

Hope that helps .

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add

```
<listener>
<listener-class>dev.myContextListenerClass</listener-class>
</listener>
```