# Less than zero sessions with HttpSessionListener

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat

I wanted to add some logic to my web application that checks the number of active sessions in my application.

For the record, I'm working with a Spring (4) application served on Tomcat 7.

This is what I implemented:

```
public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionCounter.class);

    private static final AtomicInteger ACTIVE_SESSIONS = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        logger.debug("session count is now: " + ACTIVE_SESSIONS.incrementAndGet());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        int sessions = ACTIVE_SESSIONS.decrementAndGet();
        logger.debug("session count is now: " + sessions);
        if (sessions < 0) {
            logger.error("number of active sessions is less than zero ({})", sessions);
        }
    }

}
```

I put in the sessions < 0 part on a lark, thinking it would never reach that point, but alas, it does.

I'm aware of the fact that multithreading and static non-constant variables are a special kind of tricky, but I don't see anything obviously wrong jumping out.

How could ACTIVE_SESSIONS become less than zero in this code?

Comment: How do you register the HttpSessionListener?

Comment: Why do you make any calculations in sessionCreated  debug message, this is very bad practice? Although, not sure that this is the problem here. But basically in future, compiler might optimize this, and treat your sting composition as lambda expression, which will be transferred to logger, and will be calculated only in debug mode.

Comment: <listener>
 <listener-class>test.setup.SessionCounter</listener-class>
</listener>

in web.xml

Comment: @mavarazy I see your point, and indeed I avoid this in the sessionDestroyed method. Will definitely change that as well, though as you, I doubt this is the cause of the issue here.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602477/session-counter-with-httpsessionlistener-and-session-count-variable-access 
Assuming there is a possibility of asynchronous multithreaded notification, it can be that destroyed might have been called prior to create. (This can happen for short requests, for example)